# Detect when UITabBarController More tab is selected

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

How can I detect when the special More tab of `UITabBarController` is selected?

`tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` tells me when a tab was selected, including the More tab. However, how can I know that the given `UIViewController` is actually the More tab?

At first I though about using the index, but that would assume that the More tab will be in the same position. Also, the title ("More") appears to be localised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it right after posting the question:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
{
    if (tabBarController.moreNavigationController == viewController) {
        NSLog(@"More");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach:

```
if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == NSNotFound) {
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @hpique http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html